# How to retrieve data from my Entitiy Model in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I created my tables, then my `Entity Model` (`Model1.edmx`).

I can drag & drop a `GridView` and `EntityDataSource` control, they work fine.

but I need to use my data model in code-behind. 

I should be able to query a single record.

For example, in `Page_Load` event I want to fill the textboxes with specific record.

I don't know where to begin with, the namespaces, instantiating the object etc. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using `WebForms`(c#) with `EntityFramework`

Comment: Which Ef? And Which WebForm version?

Comment: ASP.NET(4) Dynamic Data Entities Web Application
EF 4

Comment: Could you please post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
        ShellEntities entities = new ShellEntities(); //initiate
        List<User> users = entities.User.Where(w => w.Email == "test@gmail.com").ToList();
        foreach (var item in users)
        {
            Response.Write(item.Username);
        }
```

I dont need to use any namespace or such thing, initiating the Entity automatically recognizes

Answer (score 0):

Try using Linq to Entities. Very useful indeed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff628210.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Entity Version? Check this is for

```
   LOJAEntities loja = new LOJAEntities();

   #region IBaseCRUD<T> Members

   public void Add(T pEntity)
    {
        loja.AddObject(pEntity.GetType().Name, pEntity);
    }

    public void Delete(T pEntity)
    {
        loja.DeleteObject(pEntity);
    }

    public void Attach(T pEntity)
    {
        loja.AttachTo(pEntity.GetType().Name, pEntity);
    }

    public void Detach(T pEntity)
    {
        loja.Detach(pEntity);
    }

    public void Update(T pEntity)
    {
        loja.ApplyCurrentValues<T>(pEntity.GetType().Name, pEntity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        try
        {
            return loja.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(where);
        }
        catch { return null; }

    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return loja.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        loja.SaveChanges();
    }

   #endregion
```

}

Reposytory use ...